# Are there problems with these categorical structure

Tags: php, mysql, woocommerce

I'm new to Woocommerce. English is not my first language so please pardon me. I've added an image hopefully it will help to illustrate better.

My Question is can one product be assigned to different category levels?

For example, product A is grouped under ***Category A > Sub-Category A*** and also under ***Category B***. Will there be maintenance or compatibility issues in this manner? Will checking or unchecking ***Category A*** makes a difference?

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h45L1.jpg)

Comment: i believe the down voters have done so because this is not a programming question and is directly related to the use of a plugin

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes you can assign products to any category or level without much of a problem, the only thing you do need to concern yourself with is user experience you do not what to create a confusing navigation root to product but in terms of using categories as filters you have no issue really